# Bundle.main.path(forResource: is always nil for files with accented chars in the name... is this a bug?

Tags: swift, swift5

Yes, I have the file included in the bundle for the target.

But this line

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "wav")
```

will always be nil if `fileName` has accented chars in the file name, like

```
autenticaçãoemcartório
armação
```

Is there a way to solve that?

Can you confirm that as a bug?

Comment: Cannot reproduce (tested with "armação.wav" in the Simulator and on a device). Are you sure that the file has the correct name?

Comment: Is your fileName `armação.wav` or `armação` (without `.wav`). Should be without, since you already have `ofType: "wav"`

Comment: strange. I cannot play any file with accents in their names. All other files play correctly. Yes, fileNames contain no extension. I typed it incorrectly here, fixed.

Comment: Have you checked if URL objects works, `Bundle.main.url(forResource:, withExtension:)`

Comment: Can you provide an example project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that your filenames are not encoded in the same Unicode form. For example, LOWERCASE SMALL LETTER O + COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT is not the same as LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH ACUTE, even though they look identical. Depending on how your filenames were created, there can be mismatches that are not "equal" in the way that Bundle treats equal. (They *may* be equal in the way that Swift.String treats equal, and still not be equal in the way that Bundle treats equal.)

Note that the filesystem on the device is not the same as the filesystem on the simulator, so things that work one place may not work another.

To explore this, start by using FileManager to enumerate the filenames in the directory. Then check their `unicodeScalars` property and compare that to the string you're looking for.

Be particularly suspicious of files that were not created and named on an Apple platform, since different platforms may have different default ways of encoding non-ASCII characters.

---

Based on your comments, your filenames are not UTF-8 encoded. They look like Latin1 (maybe created on Windows?)

Comment: is there a way to convert all files on a mac to have the right encoding of their filenames? The files are wav.

Comment: tested the word `aeromoça` and its file encoding name has the following unicodeScalars: 80 84 45 97 101 114 111 109 111 231 97 46 119 97 118... the same word if I simply make  a let name = "aeromoça", is 80 84 45 97 101 114 111 109 111 231 97. Now the big question is, how do I convert that?

Comment: I have several theories on how I'd attack the problem, but I don't have time today to build test cases to see which would work reliably. But one possible solution would be to just rename the files, re-typing the filenames (since I assume you're typing the filenames into Swift). Or cut-and-pasting the names from one place to the other to try to capture the same symbols.

Comment: Updated the answer; your files don't have the names you think they do.

Comment: the word is aeromoça, not aeromoa... no difference using the canonical map stuff.

Comment: I know; I'm just telling you what that sequence of bytes decodes as. If you got that from FileManager, the file on disk is named `PT-aeromoa.wav`.

Comment: ah, sorry. In my code I have this "PT-" prefix. The sequence 80 84 45 97 101 114 111 109 111 231 97 46 119 97 118 is for "PT-aeromoça"... again is not "PT-aeromoa"... the files on the disk have this prefix. But does not mind, because all files are found, except for the ones with accented chars. I have two options: (1) discover how to convert the string to match the way it is encoded on the file system or (2) I enumerate the files using File Manager until I find one that `hasPrefix` equal to the one I want. This (2) is the stupid way, and I don't like it.

Comment: Sorry; misread my decoder. It was dropping invalid characters. Your string is not UTF-8. It's in Latin-1. Retyping the filenames may fix it. You can also write a small shell script using `iconv` to rename the files. (But I can't do that right now. I may have time to look at it tomorrow)

Comment: These filenames, 3000 in total, were created by AppleScript, by reading names from a txt file... and when that txt file is open I have instructed AppleScript to open it as UTF8... anyway I will check that

Comment: I will accept your answer because you pointed me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: That's probably the mistake. If the file is encoded in Latin1, you should open it in Latin1. If you read it as UTF-8, that would create exactly the problems you're describing.